# objdump -i doesn't show all possible output formats

Tags: gcc, linker, linker-scripts

I was trying to understand command [OUTPUT_FORMAT()](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Building_Cross_Toolchains_with_gcc?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=billgatliff-toolchains.pdf) in GCC linker, they didn't mention what are the possible values for the arguments like for example :

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-littlearm", "elf32-littlearm", "elf32-littlearm")
```

where is the documentation for `"elf32-littlearm"` and the other parameters?, what are the possible other values? these are all not mentioned. nevertheless, I found [this GCC document](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Building_Cross_Toolchains_with_gcc?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=billgatliff-toolchains.pdf)  as they stated on **page 10** and I quote:

> Use the objdump utility to find out which formats are supported by
> your target’s version of the linker

I searched a lot and found [this tutorial](https://blog.thea.codes/the-most-thoroughly-commented-linker-script/) giving the suggestion of using the command:

```
objdump -i
```

so I ran this command on my Windows machine and I got this result:

```
pe-x86-64
 (header little endian, data little endian)
  i386
pei-x86-64
 (header little endian, data little endian)
  i386
pe-bigobj-x86-64
 (header little endian, data little endian)
  i386
elf64-x86-64
 (header little endian, data little endian)
  i386
elf64-l1om
 (header little endian, data little endian)
  l1om
elf64-k1om
 (header little endian, data little endian)
  k1om
pe-i386
 (header little endian, data little endian)
  i386
pei-i386
 (header little endian, data little endian)
  i386
elf32-i386
 (header little endian, data little endian)
  i386
elf32-iamcu
 (header little endian, data little endian)
  iamcu
elf64-little
 (header little endian, data little endian)
  i386
  l1om
  k1om
  iamcu
elf64-big
 (header big endian, data big endian)
  i386
  l1om
  k1om
  iamcu
elf32-little
 (header little endian, data little endian)
  i386
  l1om
  k1om
  iamcu
elf32-big
 (header big endian, data big endian)
  i386
  l1om
  k1om
  iamcu
srec
 (header endianness unknown, data endianness unknown)
  i386
  l1om
  k1om
  iamcu
symbolsrec
 (header endianness unknown, data endianness unknown)
  i386
  l1om
  k1om
  iamcu
verilog
 (header endianness unknown, data endianness unknown)
  i386
  l1om
  k1om
  iamcu
tekhex
 (header endianness unknown, data endianness unknown)
  i386
  l1om
  k1om
  iamcu
binary
 (header endianness unknown, data endianness unknown)
  i386
  l1om
  k1om
  iamcu
ihex
 (header endianness unknown, data endianness unknown)
  i386
  l1om
  k1om
  iamcu
plugin
 (header little endian, data little endian)

         pe-x86-64 pei-x86-64 pe-bigobj-x86-64 elf64-x86-64 elf64-l1om
    i386 pe-x86-64 pei-x86-64 pe-bigobj-x86-64 elf64-x86-64 ----------
    l1om --------- ---------- ---------------- ------------ elf64-l1om
    k1om --------- ---------- ---------------- ------------ ----------
   iamcu --------- ---------- ---------------- ------------ ----------

         elf64-k1om pe-i386 pei-i386 elf32-i386 elf32-iamcu elf64-little
    i386 ---------- pe-i386 pei-i386 elf32-i386 ----------- elf64-little
    l1om ---------- ------- -------- ---------- ----------- elf64-little
    k1om elf64-k1om ------- -------- ---------- ----------- elf64-little
   iamcu ---------- ------- -------- ---------- elf32-iamcu elf64-little

         elf64-big elf32-little elf32-big srec symbolsrec verilog tekhex binary
    i386 elf64-big elf32-little elf32-big srec symbolsrec verilog tekhex binary
    l1om elf64-big elf32-little elf32-big srec symbolsrec verilog tekhex binary
    k1om elf64-big elf32-little elf32-big srec symbolsrec verilog tekhex binary
   iamcu elf64-big elf32-little elf32-big srec symbolsrec verilog tekhex binary

         ihex plugin
    i386 ihex ------
    l1om ihex ------
    k1om ihex ------
   iamcu ihex ------
```

and clearly, there is no mention for `elf32-littlearm` so this brings up my main question, where is the documentation related to `elf32-littlearm` and what are other possible values?

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of searching, I figured out it's dependent on the toolchain you are using. in my case, the command `objdump` came from an installed `Arduino` toolchain.

so I searched for a toolchain specific to arm architecture which is [arm GNU toolchain](https://developer.arm.com/downloads/-/arm-gnu-toolchain-downloads), installed it, added its path to the environment path, and executed the command:

```
arm-none-eabi-objdump -i
```

and this was the result:

```
BFD header file version (Arm GNU Toolchain 12.3.Rel1 (Build arm-12.35)) 2.40.0.20230627
elf32-littlearm
 (header little endian, data little endian)
  arm
elf32-littlearm-fdpic
 (header little endian, data little endian)
  arm
elf32-bigarm
 (header big endian, data big endian)
  arm
elf32-bigarm-fdpic
 (header big endian, data big endian)
  arm
elf32-little
 (header little endian, data little endian)
  arm
elf32-big
 (header big endian, data big endian)
  arm
srec
 (header endianness unknown, data endianness unknown)
  arm
symbolsrec
 (header endianness unknown, data endianness unknown)
  arm
verilog
 (header endianness unknown, data endianness unknown)
  arm
tekhex
 (header endianness unknown, data endianness unknown)
  arm
binary
 (header endianness unknown, data endianness unknown)
  arm
ihex
 (header endianness unknown, data endianness unknown)
  arm
plugin
 (header little endian, data little endian)

         elf32-littlearm elf32-littlearm-fdpic elf32-bigarm elf32-bigarm-fdpic
     arm elf32-littlearm elf32-littlearm-fdpic elf32-bigarm elf32-bigarm-fdpic

         elf32-little elf32-big srec symbolsrec verilog tekhex binary ihex
     arm elf32-little elf32-big srec symbolsrec verilog tekhex binary ihex

         plugin
     arm ------
```

so I concluded that no toolchain can support all targets, so the parameters of OUTPUT_FORMAT() are dependent on the toolchain.